# using perl/regex to upper \U in stringr

Tags: r, regex, stringr

Is it possible to use perl expressions in `stringr` functions?

For example:

```
> sub("(Hi)", "\\U\\1",  "Hi, how's it going?", perl = T)
[1] "HI, how's it going?"
```

This fails in `stringr`:

```
> str_replace("Hi, how's it going?", "(Hi)", "\\U\\1")
[1] "1, how's it going?"
```

I'm working in tidyverse idiom, so I'd like to use `str_replace` rather than `sub`. And good to know in general.

Comment: Do you plan to only uppercase some specific parts of matches, or the whole matches? You can't use PCRE with stringr functions, BTW.

Comment: only specific letters so `toupper` etc won’t do the trick

Comment: `toupper` will do the trick in the case you posted. If your pattern is `(H)(i)` and you want to replace with `hI`, then it is not working.

Comment: Does this question actually have anything to do with Perl?

Comment: @Shawn yes `\U` is perl-flavored regex so provides context to the regex being used.

Comment: But you're not actually using Perl? If not it shouldn't be tagged perl.

Comment: @Shawn feel free to edit. SO's system recommends tagging regex questions with a specific language, so i did. definitely is relevant to the question, but perhaps doesn't need the tag.

Comment: From the [perl] tag description: *For Perl-style regular expressions in other languages, use the regex tag, or, if they are based on the PCRE library, the pcre tag.*

Comment: @Shawn got it, thanks. that's helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may change the case, or manipulate in any other way, the whole match in *stringr* `str_replace`:

```
library(stringr)
str_replace("Hi, how's it going?", "Hi", function(m) str_to_upper(m))
## => [1] "HI, how's it going?"
str_replace("Hi, how's it going?", "Hi", function(m) toupper(m))
## => [1] "HI, how's it going?"
```

However, since the anonymous function only allows the whole match value to be passed into it there is no such flexibility as with `(g)sub`, this won't work:

```
str_replace("Hi, how's it going?", "(H)(i)", function(m,n) paste0(str_to_lower(m),str_to_upper(n)))
```

Tested with *stringr_1.4.0*.